# Album art is not displaying correct when I use AsyncTask class

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-cursor

When I display album art directly in my music app, it hangs. In stackoverflow, someone suggested me to implemented AsyncTask. So, I implemented **AsyncTask** to make my app faster. Right now, my app is not hanging but it is not displaying correct album art. And album arts are random means changing frequently when I scroll my listview.

Please help me.

Here is AsyncTask class :

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;
    private long l;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, long l) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        this.l = l;
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        //Bitmap art = getAlbumart(songlist.this, l);
        Context context = songlist.this;
        Bitmap bm = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        try {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, l);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (pfd != null) {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
                pfd = null;
                fd = null;
            }
        } catch (Error ee) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                iv_art.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                iv_art.setImageResource(R.mipmap.app_splash_screen_icon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My class which displays song in the listview :

```
public class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    String backgroundColor = "white";
    String someOtherBackgroundColor = "#FAFAFA";

    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration, R.id.iv_art});
    }



    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


        if (cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor(someOtherBackgroundColor));
        }


        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        iv_art = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_art);


        String a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));


        l = Long.parseLong(a);

        bwc = new BitmapWorkerTask(iv_art,l);

        bwc.execute();

        long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        name.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

        Utility d = new Utility();

        String durationInMin = d.convertDuration(durationInMs);

        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songlist_listitem, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of row reordering.  The image view you want to load it into when you start a fetch is not necessarily where you want to load it at the end.  The weak reference isn't helping because the view isn't being destroyed, its just not the right one anymore.

Instead of loading the data directly into the view, store it in a cache, then call notifyDataSetChanged.  When you bind the row, check and see if the image is int he cache.  If so, use it.  If not, send the request.  That will fix the majority of the issues you see, and prevent OOM errors (you can put a max memory usage on the cache).

Or use a library that does all this for you, like Volley.

Comment: This problem is not solved by cache the bitmap @Gabe